# use Android App Bundle to decrease react-native apk size

Tags: android, react-native, android-app-bundle

Is there a way to use Android App Bundle for decreasing android app size,and Deliver features on-demand in react-native project?

Answer (score 1):

A recent pull request added support for Android App Bundles

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/23239

It is not well documented, but it works if you make the required alterations.

References:

- https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/issues/91
- https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/
- https://medium.com/@AndreSand/android-app-bundle-96ac16b36875

Answer (score 0):

Probably too early for other native libs to adjust, but if you create a project with just your react native code you could try it. React Native lets you write as much native code as you like, so feel free to give it a try.